# Is there a reputable copy of Kants anthropology online?

Tags: epistemology, kant

I've looked through Google, but haven't found one; is it seen as a minor and unimportant work as one generally doesn't hear of it given the prominence of his three critiques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the three critiques, there isn't an out-of-copyright English translation of Kant's anthropology. If you can read German, there's a digitised version [here](http://www.korpora.org/Kant/aa07/117.html).

Historically speaking, Kant's *Anthropology* hasn't received nearly as much attention as the three critiques. The anthropology probably is quite significant for understanding Kant's system on his own terms---if nothing else, the *Anthropology* is Kant's distillation of the course taught every year for 25 years, including during the period when he was writing the critiques. Some of the key ways the anthropology fits into Kant's system are explained [in this review](http://ndpr.nd.edu/news/22990-anthropology-from-a-pragmatic-point-of-view/) of the most recent translation. That said, the three critiques are far more important to understanding responses to Kant's philosophy and Kant's place in the history of philosophy.

Comment: To add to this answer, note that the title is *Anthropology from a Pragmatic Point of View* which means it is non-critical and more an observation science than part of his critical philosophy. Thus, it has in general proven to be of less interest, though see Louden's *Kant's Imperfect Ethics* (coincidentally written by the translator of the *Anthropology* https://books.google.co.jp/books/about/Kant_s_Impure_Ethics.html?id=EA3YBJXLA20C&redir_esc=y).